# SQLAlchemy - MS Access connection failure

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

I am trying to connect to MS Access using sql alchemy. My access is 64 bit. I have tried with both 32-bit python and 64-bit python. The results are the same.

It works using pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class MSAccessConnector:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def test_connection(self):
        try:

            conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C://Users//Gautam Sardana//Documents//gautam.accdb;')

            cursor = conn.cursor()
            return cursor


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    pass

MSAccessConnector().test_connection()
```

But fails with sqlalchemy:

```
import pyodbc 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class MSAccessConnector:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def test_connection(self):
        try:

            engine = create_engine(r'access:///C:/Users/Gautam Sardana/Documents/gautam.accdb')
            return engine

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        pass

    def connect(self):
        pass

MSAccessConnector().test_connection()
```

I get the error:

> Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access

Answer (score 1):

The  [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect uses a connection URI of the form

```
access+pyodbc:// ...
```

The previous `access:// ...` form is no longer supported.

You also *cannot* simply supply the path to the Access database file, e.g.

```
access+pyodbc:///C:/Users/Gautam Sardana/Documents/gautam.accdb
```

Instead, you must supply the name of an ODBC System/User DSN or a pass-through ODBC connection string. For example, for a System or User DSN named "accessDatabase1" that points to a normal, unprotected Access database file you would use

```
access+pyodbc://@accessDatabase1
```

See the  ["Getting Connected" wiki page](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/Getting-Connected) for details.

Comment: For this, I am getting the error "Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc"

Comment: Did you `pip install sqlalchemy-access` ...?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I have a question, will it work using sqlite?

Comment: Yes, SQLAlchemy will work with SQLite. You don't need an external dialect for that.

Comment: The link included says you can in fact connect with a connection string instead of a DSN. I this functionality new or is the info deprecated?